# How to dual boot Windows 8 and ubuntu 14.04 on Acer Aspire 7551G

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I recently got an Acer Aspire 7551G on which i installed Windows 8. That worked fine. Now installed Ubuntu 14.04 and apart from the first successful boot, every other attempt to go to Ubuntu takes me straight in windows 8. I did some research online and i found out that i had to disable secure boot in UEFI mode. But When I go into BIOS, i don't see anything like UEFI of secure boot anywhere. I would appreciate any help on this issue please.

Thanks in advance.

Yes! both headings are there. Security and Boot. under Security I have the following: 
Set Supervisor Password, Set User Password, Set HDD Password and Password on Boot. Under Boot, I have IDE0:, CD/DVD, Network Boot, USB HDD, USB FDD and USB CD/DVD. All the above are under a broad caption Boot priority order.

And no! Booting does't take me to GRUB first. it takes me straight to Windows 8.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us some of the options you see in your BIOS? I imagine there's a header that goes something like 'boot' or 'security'. What's there?

Also, when you do try to enter ubuntu, does it take you to GRUB first?

Comment: http://acer--uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/27102/~/accessing-the-uefi-%28bios%29-setup-on-a-windows-8-system

Answer (score 0):

If it is an American Megatrends "Aptio" as found on Asus computers Legacy mode [BIOS] is called "Compatibility Support Module" or "CSM". Gives you an idea of how far out the name for UEFI, EFI, or secure boot could be.
I found this in a document I am using for my install. It is found at

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI,

[Unfortunately ubuntu.com does not have a link on the home page to the documentation site that I could find, so be sure to type in the "help." before the ubuntu.com. There is much more in the document that might help. Also the category "BootAndPartition" contains other pages of interest and is found at:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CategoryBootAndPartition

If you have not disabled BIOS Fast Boot, disable it. Enabled it bypasses the UEFI boot choice screen on my HP110-22z. Then try a re-boot.

The AMI bios version 80.1 [on a HP110-220z installed 4/19/2014] has a tab titled `Security` in the top menu. Fast Boot and Legacy support settings are also found there. 
In your case tabs titled `Advanced` or `Power on` may hold it. Leave no sub, sub menu unread.

If still no success find the name, version and date of the BIOS on your machine, as would help others here answer your question.

If it is not provided in `About` then a utility like `Speccy` will list it.
Try searching for the bios name or manufacturer on the web. A specification sheet could settle whether the option exists, what different name the BIOS maker uses for it, and where to find it if it does exist.